# ruby (w/rails) group_by, then group_by again

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, group-by

Is there a better way to do the following?

```
prices = Price...all.group_by(&:foreign_key_id)
@prices = Hash.new
prices.each {|k, v| @prices[k] = Hash.new if !@prices[k]; @prices[k] = v.group_by {|g| g.created_at.to_time.to_i } }
```

I'd like to do something like

```
prices.each {|k,v| v = v.group_by(&:created_at) }
```

But this doesn't seem to work because v is an array and group_by produces a hash. Perhaps there's a way to do this with inject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
prices.inject(Hash.new{ |h, k| h[k] = {} }) { |h, (k, v)|
  h[k] = v.group_by(&:created_at)
  h
}
```

**Added:** Less function way:

```
prices.keys.each { |k|
  prices[k] = prices[k].group_by(&:created_at)
}
```

Comment: prices.each_key.to_a   ~>   prices.keys

Comment: It's always good to see a good use of inject, and while it makes sense after looking at it, I would've never known to do that, thanks!

Comment: @aaz Thanks, I started from `.each_key { |k| ...` and finally created something extremely complex. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

may be

```
prices.each {|k,v| prices[k] = v.group_by(&:created_at) }
```

or

```
new_prices = {}
prices.each {|k,v| new_prices[k] = v.group_by(&:created_at) }
```

<strike>Hash doesn't support inject</strike>

Comment: Of course hashes support `inject`: `{}.methods.grep /inj/ #=> [:inject]`. `h = {a: 1, b: 2} ; h.inject(0) { |s, (k,v)| s + v } #=> 3`.

Comment: It supports inject as any class that implements `each` and `include Enumerable`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
prices = Price...all.inject({}) do |hash, el|
  (hash[el.foreign_key_id] ||={})[el.created_at] << el
  hash
end
```

but I doubt that you will have two records with the same `created_at` value.

You may need set format for `created_at`.

Something like this:

```
prices = Price...all.inject({}) do |hash, el|
  (hash[el.foreign_key_id] ||={})[el.created_at.to_s(:db)] << el
  hash
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand the second group_by, but the first one I think it will be a Model logic, so, depend on your type of relation you can use in your model the options: `:uniq => true` or `:group => 'foreign_key_id'` . You can read it here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: You mean using :group on the `has_many` clause? I haven't tried that, but I'd have to add another has_many line, calling it something else. I don't always use the prices grouped.